# How can Google Analytics be used to track the different websites within a homegrown CMS?

Tags: google-analytics

I own and operate my own Content Management System (CMS) web application targeted at a specific type of customer (schools).  Each customer wants to track the traffic to their own website.  Of course, I could ask them to each create their own Google Analytics account and then provide me with the tracking ID so that my CMS can embed the correct code onto their pages.  But I was wondering if there was a better way ... something more automated, and something that involves less work on their part.

I was thinking that for each customer, I could use the Google Analytics APIs to automatically create a new Property with the appropriate filter and then give the customer "Read & Analyze" permissions for that property.  The problem with that is that I'm limited to creating 50 properties under my account.

Any other ideas?  I'm just wondering if I'm missing some feature of GA that is specifically designed for this scenario.

Thanks,
Rajeev

Comment: Offtopic. This doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

Asking each user to create their own analytics account is the correct solution. Then they should just give your cms the id, and then your cms should include the correct analytics javascript code. It's the way all other cms systems supports Google Analytics